# Scala value is not stored in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
var cnt = 0
val newRDD = oldRDD.map({ list =>
        ...some work
        cnt = cnt + 1
        println(cnt) // print 1, 2, 3.. well
        newList // will store in new RDD
    })

//out side of map
println(cnt) // It's 0. Why?
```

As log, print inside of map is first and then print out side of map. Why isn't cnt value stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark transformations should be **pure functions** - receive input, produce output, without **changing state** or having any **side-effects**. Your example violates these.

What happens here is:

- The anonymous function passed as argument to `map` is **serialized and sent to workers**
- The initial value of `cnt` is serialized with it
- `cnt` is 0 when *deserialized* on each worker
- Now, each worker increments `cnt` *locally*
- That's it... the `cnt` value in *driver* application stays unchanged

As an alternative, you can use Spark's [Accumulators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators) to achieve these types of "counters".

Comment: Thanks, It help me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

In the Spark framework, when you use an external variable in a closure, it is sent automatically to the worker nodes. Each tasks get a new copy of the variable but if you update the variable in the task (this is what happens with your code), the framework does not send it back and synchronize it with the rest of the program, because it would be too expensive to do so.

If you're using external variables in the closures, you can think of it as read-only variables.

If you're trying to count how many elements you mapped, you can use `oldRDD.count()`/ `newRDD.count()` in the first place (since it seems you don't filter elements, it should give the same result).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check this first to understand the shared variables in Spark : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables